# Multi connection to Access database accdb

Tags: database, ms-access, client-server, ms-access-2016

I'm building online examination system and i want to use accdb for database. My question is will accdb allow multiple students to read the test from the database?

Answer (score 1):

not clear what you mean by on-line? Do you mean you are building a web based applcation of some sort?

Access does allow multiple users to work against the database at the same time. This typically means that you split the database into a front end (application part) and the back end - a accDB with just the tables.

And you can use the access database (engine) to drive data for a web site. However, you don't and can't use VBA or the access forms for this purpose.

Since you ONLY useing the tables and not anything else releated to Access when you build such a on-line system? Then in most cases, little if any reason exists to use the access data engine, since any of the business code and UI will be built with different tools then Access. And every web site hosting these days offers MySQL, or SQL server or some other database.

These other database systems are far more approcilate and work better with multi-user operations.

So, keep in mind when you use the term "Access", you are talking about two parts:

The data base engine - (ACE, or previous called JET). This data engine (like most database engines) does not provide any UI, reporting or anything, but is just a system to hold the tables and data. You then write the web based "on-line" software with asp.net, or whatever technology stack that you are familier with.

The 2nd part of access is the so called IDE (integrated development enviroment). That part of access lets you write code, build forms, and build reports. However, that part is not web based, and thus using the term "on-line" does not really apply here. Access IDE when used is strictly 100% desktop only.

In fact, often, if you need a multi-user applcation, we often will build + use MS-Access to build that windows desktop software, but will still choose to use a server based database system like SQL server or mySQL.

So, access alone does not really give rise to a "on-line" system, and that would require that you adopt a set of web based development tools.